# cat file | … vs … <file and my minesweeper

Tags: bash

I am seeking the explanation and deeper understanding the behaviour of `cat file | ...`  vs `... < file`.

I am coding a minesweeper for my assignment, it requires to handle the error instruction and terminate the program once error instruction enter.
however when I experiment it will the commands. the `cat` command did not let the program exit until I press enter one more time. but the `<` command working fine.

would anyone tell me how `cat input.in - | ./game4` work and why it waiting for my to press enter one more time ?

- [Manual keyboard input for my homework--minesweeper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIRHN.jpg)
- [cat input.in feed minesweeper data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIYIs.jpg)

I am currently doing my assignment, everything is going well and I am studying university of Sydney. However they are hopeless to answer my question.I had very bad experience with them so far. long story short.
So I would please any one help me because I just a beginner and I already try my best to read all sort of documentation however I am not really good at reading plain text without any example.

Comment: If the `input.in` file is small enough, then `cat input.in -` reads and writes the whole file to the pipe, and then reads standard input (the keyboard), looking for the EOF marker (control-D on Unix, control-Z on Windows).  If the game has exited, when you type the extra newline, it writes that to the pipe, and because the pipe is broken (the game exited), `cat` exits (dies from a SIGPIPE signal, probably).

Comment: I think this relates more to the difference between `<` and `|` in Linux/Unix than to any specific command such as `cat`. [Maybe relevant](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172982/what-is-the-difference-between-redirection-and-pipe). If you simply want to feed data to your program `cat` probably isn't necessary - stick with  `<`

Answer (score 3):

Fiona, you have provided a perfect example of an *Unnecessary Use of cat* (termed *UUoC*). `cat` is short for *concatenate*. It's purpose is to concatenate (join) the text from several files into a new file (e.g. `cat file1 file2 file3 > newfile4`) Its default behavior when only 1 file is given is to concatenate to `stdout` (and this default behavior is what prompts all the misuse).

`cat input.in - | ./game4` isn't a concatenation expression, you are simply using `cat` to *redirect* the output from `input.in` to the `game4` process. (the additional `'-'` you provide to indicate `stdin` is why your program is waiting until you type something -- it is not needed in a UUoC) Further every time you pipe the output of `cat` to some other program, you force the other program to run in another *subshell* unnecessarily.

What you want to do is *redirect* input to your program. That is what the *redirection* operator `'<'` is for. When you redirect input into your program with `./game4 < yourinputfile` no additional subshell is needed and the redirection operator is doing what it was created to do.

If you ever find yourself doing `cat whatever | ...`, you should think "Ugh! another UUoC, and smile because now you have learned the difference.

Comment: Lol: we both mention useless use of cat. :P

Comment: Yep, saw that, there is a never-ending stream of UUoCs that masquerade as redirection on stack overflow. There is some popular web-tutorial somewhere that must explain that as a correct way of doing redirection... Who knows.

Comment: But in this case as `cat` is taking the place of `read` it actually offers a bit more brevity, albeit making things somewhat confusing given the order-dependent nature of the `-` argument.  Definitely other ways you can do it, but this is pretty short in terms of what's being accomplished and it sort of makes sense as in this case you'd probably have some general settings that get read in, and then the actual user keypresses to play.  It's kludgy, but I like that it's short!

Comment: It is certainly something that your can tailor to your needs. Thankfully, the use of `cat` in these circumstances is no longer a *hanging-offense*. So there are little cases where it may be the natural choice. Good point.

Comment: well thank you first, I learnt UUoC now. As first learn the bash command, it is very hard to read those plain english with endless term STD EOF etc. as I am beginner. I feel here is much better as most of you are very kind and easy to understand. thank you again

Answer (score 2):

## `Cat`

`cat` is a command that *concatenate files*, now `-` is considered to be a marker that says it should read from STDIN, in this case the terminal, so:

```
cat file -
```

will first echo the entire content of `file` and next echo everything you say through the command line. You can say you are done saying things by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

In order to let `cat` shut up when `file` is echoed, you simply have to write:

```
cat file
```

But this is an excellent example of the [*useless use of `cat`*](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

### Pipe

What you describe is a pipe (`|`). If you put a pipe in between two commands, like:

```
command1 | command2
```

the output of `command1` is fed as input to `command2`. So if you write:

```
cat file | command
```

it will feed the content of `file` to `command`.

## I/O redirection

`<` is not a command, it is one of the examples of *I/O redirection*. The line:

```
command < file
```

means you feed the content of `file` to command as input.

## Long story short:

> ```
> cat file | command
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> command < file
> ```
>
> are equivalent, although the `cat` version is probably computationally more expensive. But
>
> ```
> cat file - | command
> ```
>
> is not.

Comment: thank you for your answer. to be honest, I am still trying to understand the command, whether it is UUoC or not, that is something uni provide and cat file - | ./program is some command I saw in the forum in my course but this command cost me 5 hours to figure out the problem is not my c program, it is the behavior of this command. when I seek further explanation. my tutors did not answer but tried to argue about my question should be public, not private. 

thank you for all the explanation here.

Answer (score 1):

## `cat`

In its simplest form without redirection `cat` takes a single argument -- a file, reads it and places the text contents of it onto `STDOUT`, which typically you'll see in your terminal.

`cat` can also place the contents of multiple files on `STDOUT` if you pass it multiple file names.  In this case, though, the second argument is a `-`.  What does that mean?

Well, according to `Manual page cat(1) line 46` (accessed via `man cat` in bash):

> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

So here you first put the contents of `input.in` in `STDOUT`, then anything typed from the keyboard (`STDIN`).

The given description is a bit confusing as it makes it sound like it only applies to a single argument, but the actual behavior is somewhat different.  It's true `cat - $filename` ignores the second argument, but if you put `-` as the final argument (e.g. `cat $filename -`, it apparently appends `STDIN` to the results, even with one or more files, somewhat contrary to the description.

The `|` sends these commands to your game program.

Note: You'll see two copies of the things you type in `STDIN`, but the game will just see one.

To learn more about redirection I recommend the following resources:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection
http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: thank you for your time and extra resource, very appreciate all sharing the knowledge with this newbie.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers have mentioned **Filter Programs**.

`cat` is the simplest of a class of programs called Filter Programs.  There are many, for example `grep`, `tail`, `head`, `sed`, etc.  Filter programs take one or more filenames as their arguments which they process from left to right.  Output is sent to *standard output*, usually abbreviated to `stdout` (from C).

A important feature is what happens if you don't supply *any* filenames.  Then a filter program will read from *standard input*, usually abbreviated to `stdin`. `stdin` is by default connected to the keyboard, but can be redirected by the shell to come from a file (`<`) or a pipe (`|`).

Remember that redirection from `stdin` is a function of the **shell**, not the filter program.

```
cat foo.txt
```

has the same functionality as:

```
cat < foo.txt
```

*except* in the first example the program `cat` opens and reads the file.  In the second it is the *shell*.

What do you think happens here?

```
cat foo.txt < bar.txt
```

Try it!  Why isn't `bar.txt` displayed?  Because a filename was supplied, and so there is no need for `cat` to read `stdin`.

A hyphen `-` is commonly used to mean "read from stdin".  So we can do this:

```
cat - foo.txt < bar.txt
```

which will read and display `bar.txt` and then `foo.txt`.

What will this do?

```
echo 'Hello' | cat foo.txt - bar.txt
```

Try it!

**EDIT:**

Although you can only have one `stdin`, you can merge file descriptors:

```
3<&0 echo 'hello' >&3|cat < gash.txt
```

A **file descriptor** (FD) is just an integer that refers to an IO stream.  Every process has a *file descriptor table*.  By convention (almost a law, but not quite):

```
FD 0 stdin
FD 1 stdout
FD 2 stderr
```

You can see that FD 3 onwards are free for the program to use.  In the convoluted example above:

```
3<&0
```

*Duplicates* file descriptor 0 (stdin) onto file descriptor 3 (see `man dup2` for the low-level mechanism).  The `&` is required to differentiate an FD from a file called "0".  So now I have two file descriptors pointing to stdin!  I redirect the `echo` to FD 3, then redirect FD 0 from the file (`<&0` is the default for `<`).

The syntax for output redirection is really `[FD]> filename`  where the FD is optional (that's what the `[ ]` mean).  The default FD when writing is 1, stdout.

The file descriptor table is copied from parent to child when a new process is created.  So when you run `cat` from the shell, all those changes to file descriptors that the shell did are copied to the `cat` program.

Comment: thank you for example. I understand < is from shell now; for the last one; I modify it as  echo 'hello' | cat foo.txt - < bar.txt  it gives me only what is in txt. no echo.

Comment: Mixing a pipe with redirection will never work, but then it is the order of the commands.  Not many people realise you can put the redirection almost anywhere.  Try `< bar.txt echo 'hello'|cat`.  That gives the `echo` but no file.  There is only one `stdin`, and it can only "point" to one place.

Comment: BUT, you can play with file descriptors.  See update in my answer.